Tkinter after using Login form, main UI changes?
I'm encountering an issue with a Tkinter application involving a login form. When I log in through the login form, the main UI does not display the image as expected; instead, it shows a grey window where the image should be. However, if I bypass the login and initialize the App class directly (i.e., not starting with main and then proceeding to login), the image loads correctly.

# Example usage
app = App("username")
app.mainloop()

#import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from ui import App

def start_login_window():
    window = ttk.Window(themename='lumen')
    window.geometry('300x180')
    window.title('Login')

    def login():
        username = inp_username.get().strip()
        if username:  # Add password conditions as needed
            window.withdraw()
            app = App(username)
            app.mainloop()
            window.destroy()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Login Failed", "Incorrect username or password")

    lbl_username = ttk.Label(window, text='Reflex Username:')
    lbl_username.pack(pady=(20, 10))
    inp_username = ttk.Entry(window)
    inp_username.pack()


    btn_login = ttk.Button(window, text='Login', command=login)
    btn_login.pack(pady=20)

    window.mainloop()


#In  App class display image functions:

class App(ttk.Window):
    def __init__(self, username, theme='lumen'):
        super().__init__(themename=theme)

        self.username = username
        self.title('Quality Control Application')
        self.scan_state = 1  # Initialize scan_state at the beginning of the App initialization
        self.scanned_data = {'SKU': None, 'GRADE': None, 'HD': None}  # Ensure scanned data is also initialized
        self.photo = None  # Image storage
        self.geometry('1700x520')
        # Set window transparency: 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.9)  # Example: 90% opacity

        self.db = DatabaseManager(self.username)

        self.scan = ScannerWorker()
        self.scan.set_on_scan_callback(self.handle_scan)
        self.scan.set_display_message_callback(self.display_message)
        self.scan.start()

        self.initialize_ui()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)   

    def initialize_ui(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        # Use a style for Treeview heading
        style.configure('Treeview.Heading', font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))  # Bold font for Treeview headers

        control_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        control_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)
        
        image_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        image_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

        self.configure_treeview(control_frame)
        self.configure_text_log(control_frame)
        self.configure_image_display(image_frame)
            # Add input field and update button
        self.create_input_and_button(control_frame)

        self.display_message("Welcome to the QC application! Please start by scanning the SKU.", color='green')
# Code to troubleshoot image not showing after login
def load_and_display_image(self, scu):
    result = self.db.get_model_link_line_category(scu)
    if result:
        link = result[0].strip()
        if link:
            self.display_image(link)
        else:
            self.display_message_img("No image available for this SKU.")
    else:
        self.display_message_img("No data or image available for this SKU.")

def display_image(self, image_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(image_url, verify=False)  # For demonstration; disable SSL verification
        if response.status_code == 200:
            img_data = response.content
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
            img = img.resize((360, 480))  # Resize the image if necessary
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)  # Store the image in a PhotoImage object

            # Configure the image label with the new PhotoImage object
            self.image_label.config(image=self.photo)
            self.image_label.image = self.photo  # Maintain a reference to the PhotoImage object
        else:
            logging.error(f"Failed to load image. HTTP status code: {response.status_code}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to load image. Error: {str(e)}")
        self.display_message_img(f"Failed to load image. Error: {str(e)}")

Could someone help me understand why the image fails to load after logging in through the login form and suggest how to fix this issue? Any advice on how to ensure the image loads correctly after the user logs in would be greatly appreciated.

It is because you have two instances of ttk.Window() (inherits from tkinter.Tk).  Try adding master=self when creating instance of ImageTk.PhotoImage(...) inside display_image().

self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgage=img, master=self)  # Store the image in a PhotoImage object
But the issue persists

Using master=self works for me.

This worked for me
def load_and_display_image(self, scu):
    result = self.db.get_model_link_line_category(scu)
    if result:
        link = result[0].strip()
        if link:
            self.display_image(link)
        else:
            self.display_message_img("No image available for this SKU.")
    else:
        self.display_message_img("No data or image available for this SKU.")

def display_image(self, image_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(image_url, verify=False)  # For demonstration; disable SSL verification
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            img_data = response.content
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
            img = img.resize((360, 480))  # Resize the image if necessary
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img, master=self) # Store the image in a PhotoImage object

            # Configure the image label with the new PhotoImage object
            self.image_label.config(image=self.photo)
            self.image_label.image = self.photo  # Maintain a reference to the PhotoImage object
        else:
            logging.error(f"Failed to load image from {image_url}. HTTP status code: {response.status_code}")
            self.display_message_img("Failed to load image: HTTP error")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to make a request to {image_url}: {e}")
        self.display_message_img(f"Failed to load image: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred while loading image: {str(e)}")
        self.display_message_img(f"Failed to load image: {str(e)}")


def display_message_img(self, message):
    self.image_label.config(text=message, image=None)  # Display the message


Thank you for self-answering your question. I took the liberty of removing the answer part from your question. You will be able to accept your own answer using the v-shaped button to its left (if not now, then after 48 hours).
